# Custom progress bar, doesn't show progress

Tags: android, xml, progress-bar, customization

In my application I'm inserting a custom progress bar.
The problem is that is not shown progress. When in the code I call `setProgress`, the bar remains with the background color. Whereas if in the layout setting `setProgress` is shown normally.
Before inserting the custom toolbar, it worked perfectly

Here is some code:

drawable/customprogressbar.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<layer-list xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">

    <!-- Define the background properties like color etc -->
    <item android:id="@android:id/background">
    <shape>
        <corners
           android:radius="5dip" />
        <gradient
                android:startColor="#5c5c5b"
                android:endColor="#9d9d9c"
                android:centerY="1"
                android:angle="270"
        />
    </shape>
   </item>


  <!-- Define the progress properties like start color, end color etc -->
  <item android:id="@android:id/progress">
    <clip>
        <shape>
            <corners
              android:radius="5dip" />
            <gradient
                android:startColor="#85040b"
                android:endColor="#e30613"
                android:centerY="1"
                android:angle="270"
            />
        </shape>
    </clip>
    </item>
</layer-list>
```

And the layout where I see the progress bar

```
 <ProgressBar
        android:id="@+id/progressBar1"
        style="@android:style/Widget.ProgressBar.Horizontal"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
        android:max="100"
        android:progress="50"
        android:layout_alignTop="@+id/map"
        android:progressDrawable="@drawable/customprogressbar"
        android:visibility="visible" />
```

In code I call

```
progresbar.setProgress(progress);
```

to set the progress

Comment: clear your question first what is working ?

Comment: Can you show us the logic.

Comment: can you share you code?

Comment: I try to explain better: When I set the progress from code, it doesnt' work. But if i set it from the layout, it show the progress.

Comment: @umerk44 which part of the code? 
simply call an async task that performs operations on a file, and progressupdate, updates the progress bar. I repeat that without changing the appearance of the bar, it works

Comment: every thing looks fine in your post. So may b i can get some thing from your code, that you are missing.

Comment: I have added another progress bar... and it doesn't work... I make a clean on the project and reboot eclipse... (now doesn't work never with the standard bar)

Comment: Edit: doesn't work after the reboot -.-

Comment: I found the error.
The code is correct. But i call "setProgress" on a "if-else" only in the if

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the error. The code is correct. But i call "setProgress" on a "if-else" only in the if  state.
this is the correct code (on the progress update of an asynctask

```
 if(i[3]==1){
                SetMarker(coordOggetto, i[0] , tipo, nome, indirizzo);}
                 progresbar.setProgress(i[1]);
                tv_completamento.setText(i[1]+"%");
            }
```

thank's all for comment

Answer (score 0):

this is a bug in `ProgressBar`

```
progressBarHandler.post(new Runnable() {

      public void run() {
          bar.setProgress(progress);
      }
});
```

can solve your progblem